# How are my values not getting assigned to my variables in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently had a post about Serialization problems and I think it turns out that I did figure out how to Serialize, but the information I was TRYING to serialize had issues that were unrelated.

```
    public GuardA () { //I have also tried void Awake() and void Start() to no avail

    profile = new StandardPlayerParadigm ();
    job = new Mercenary ();
    type = new GuardPrototype ();

    //decl the stats

    profile.Name = "Guard A";
    profile.stdType = type.stdType; //Which child of StandardType?
    profile.Profession = job.Job; //Class
    profile.ProfessionDescription = job.JobDescription; //ClassDescription 
    profile.Level = 1;
    profile.Health = type.Health;
    profile.Mana = type.Mana;
    profile.TP = type.TP;
    profile.Attack = type.Attack;
    profile.Defense = type.Defense;
    profile.MagicAttack = type.MagicAttack;
    profile.MagicDefense = type.MagicDefense;
    profile.Critical = type.Critical;
    profile.Dexterity = type.Dexterity;
    profile.HitRate = type.HitRate;
}
```

Specifically, the above.

This is part of a larger Guard.cs code found at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alucard55/91e78c0488e84ccafa5aa183857d1686).

It interacts with 3 scripts that all inherit information from parent classes, but all you need to know is one controls stats and should assign them, another should give the name of a Profession and Description of it.

StandardPlayerParadigm is the script that should coalesce all of the variables that the character should use. Thus, when trying to assign the variables OF this a value, I'm trying to use the Mercenary profession and the GuardPrototype to do this.

But in the inspector, Unity is telling me none of this is getting passed and everything is a null value or 0 where applicable.

I know the information is THERE, though, because when making the Mercenary variable and the GuardPrototype variable public instead of private, the Inspector is showing the values I want.

So TL;DR, my values are not getting assigned to the variables I want.

Why is this not getting assigned? What do I need to do in order to do it, and is there anything I should know going forward about this sort of thing (as in, is it easy to mess up like I did, or did I just do a dumb)?

Let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: Are you assinging GuardA as a script to one of your GameObjects?  GuardA isn't inheriting from MonoBehaviour in the code that you have posted.

Comment: That's my bad. I forgot that I did not re-upload that edit. I AM using Monobehaviour currently. I will update the gist accordingly.And yes, I am putting it on an empty gameObject in order to see this in the inspector.

Comment: See if this help http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/727892/script-default-variable-value-behaviour.html.  The gist of it is that once you assign a script to a game object, it won't dynamically update itself from your code in the editor.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I do have one follow up question if you happen to know.

Are you aware of if this will allow a field to be changed and re-saved? By that I mean, let's say level goes up and then stats change. Does this present any problems for saving that information? (Still learning some basics that go into saving a character).

Comment: If you run your game, change some values, and then stop your game, your game objects will revert to their original values in the editor.  But since it looks like you're setting all of your values through code once your game starts running, you shouldn't have to worry about the values being shown in the editor.  Personally, I wouldn't make fields visible in the editor if you're always going to be setting their values through code.  You could make them properties instead of fields or you could use the [HideInInspector] attribute if you still want them to be public fields.

Comment: If you're trying to save player data from one game to the next, you could use PlayerPrefs or do XML serialization.

Comment: Yeah currently I'm doing XML Serialization. Would the logic that a player takes the GuardA.cs script (for example), then I pull the info from that, save it, and then manipulate the /saved/ info with respect to loading and altering?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.